# How do I make my bot send a message after user has replied to a question

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a system where a user is given a question by the bot and after the user replies it clears these 2 messages and asks another question and repeats until all the questions are complete.

I can't make it to wait for the user to input their answer before asking another question, any help?

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const clearMessages = require("./clearMessages");

const askEventQuestions = async (client, channelId) => {
  const edonoChannel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  let q1Answer = ""

  //event questions embeds
  const q1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("AQUA")
    .setDescription("What Type of Event would you like to donate for?");

  const q2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("AQUA")
    .setDescription("What are the amounts of DMC/Items that you are donating?");


  //send and set answer for questions

  await edonoChannel.send({ embeds: [q1] });
  client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    q1Answer = message.content;
    if (q1Answer !== "") {
      await clearMessages(2, message);
      console.log(q1Answer);
    }
  });

  await edonoChannel.send({ embeds: [q2] });
```

Comment: Use collectors to await for user answer

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft Can you show me a snippet of how to do so since i am not familiar with them

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#collectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Collectors** and I think **awaitMessages** : https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages

Its a totally different way to do it but simpler

Something like that :

```js
const isValid = response => response.content == ''
const question = await edonoChannel.send({ embeds: [q1] })

const stepper = await question.channel.awaitMessages({isValid, your options ?})

const answer = stepper.first().content 
// this is your answer content, the data is necessarily the unique valid response, thanks to isValid function

await question.delete()
await stepper.delete()

...
```

That is returning the first message (or messages) that contain(s) the valid answer to your question. After that you can run your treatement!

Comment: But how do i store the data send and delete the messages and ask the next ones?

Comment: Can you further show how you would complete the code to store the message content and delete the messages? sorry but i dont know what to do next

Comment: I just edited my answer but I dont understand what do you mean by store the content

Comment: you don't need to "store" the content you can just define the message content and then use it elsewhere.

Comment: When i console.log(stepper.first().content) it doesn't log anything

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out, in your example, isValid should be in between the curly braces aswell

Comment: oh sorry, all good now then?

Comment: yeah works perfectly, ill accept your solution, just change that part so when people use it, it works